# Application migrated from Expo to ReactNative not running in Android Emulator

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I have converted Expo app to react-native by following expo kit document. Everything seems to be good. If I open android folder in android studio, I have not seen any issue. But when I run ' react-native run-android ' command it is giving below error.

---- Error message ----
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

Android studio configured as per document and enumulator is running.
I searched in google to resolve this issue and tried the options below Reinstalling npm, cleaning,and re-running.

Any help to solve this issue will be of great help for me to continue my application development.

Comment: Did you try `adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081`

Comment: Hi Piyush, It is not working below is the error
adb : The term 'adb' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Comment: can you share ---Error message---.

Comment: Below is the error
adb : The term 'adb' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, 
verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (adb:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: Have you gone through this conversation: https://www.thecustomdroid.com/install-adb-windows-linux-macos/.? did it help you